# How to swap an image on click

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile-safari

How can I pass the value after `onClick` event in JavaScript where that particular value is checked in another function? This is a html page in a webview in an iphone application.

Actually, I want to change the image of a button after clicking on that image, with a different value.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is your question a HTML/JS question or an iOS/CocoaTouch question? Where is this image you want to change?

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity, but it is still kind of difficult to figure out exactly what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's really the image that is clicked, and not an enclosing link, this should do:

```
<img src="foo.png" onclick="this.src='bar.png';" />
```